# Como podría escribir este código? Funciones y Arrays JS

Tags: javascript

Estoy empezando a estudiar programación y a través de un ejercicio que me han propuesto me han surgido dudas acerca de como pasarlo a código.

> Crea ahora una función `empujarHeroe` que reciba un argumento
> `arrayHeroes` (será un *array*) y otro argumento `nuevoHeroe` (será un
> *string*) y empuje dentro de `arrayHeroes` el argumento `nuevoHeroe`.

Y esta otra

> Invoca a la función `empujarHeroe` enviando el array `superheroes` y
> el string **"Thor"**.

Las dos ideas que tenia son las siguientes, pero al darme error estoy seguro de que tengo errores de syntaxis por todos lados,(estoy aprendiendo).

```javascript
function empujarHeroe(arrayHeroes[],  "nuevoHeroe") {
  return arrayHeroes.push("nuevoHeroe");
}
```

```javascript
empujarHeroe(superheroes[], "Thor");
```

Muchas gracias a quien me pueda responder.

Comment: Bienvenido/a [es.so]: haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _¿Y los errores?_ Pulsa en [edit] y agrega más detalles a tu pregunta. Además, modifica su título, ya que leyéndolo a simple vista suena a que quieres que hagamos un tarea (¡y no lo hacemos!). Lee [ask].

Comment: Te sobran los corchetes tanto en la implementación de la función como en la llamada

Comment: @padaleiana claro que quiere que le ayudemos a realizar esta tarea, pero en este caso lo ha intentado y no estaba tan lejos de conseguirlo, de ahí mi respuesta con explicación extensa para que lo aprenda por si el profe le pregunta (y si no lo quiere aprender pues bueno, allá el... como me decia un profe a veces, "yo te apruebo, pues en todo caso ya te suspenderá la vida").

Comment: @masterguru no dije que no podamos ayudarle (demostró que lo intentó), dije que no debe parecer que quiere que le hagamos la tarea (por eso hice énfasis al título) :)

Comment: @padaleiana sí, perdona, me di cuenta despues de mi comentario, tienes razón, ese título llama a pensar que no ha hecho nada

Comment: tenéis razón en que la pregunta da a pensar que simplemente esperaba la respuesta para terminar rápido el ejercicio, intentare pensar mejor como formular este tipo de dudas ya que llevaba unas cuantas horas volviéndome loco y no entendía que podía pasar, de momento debido a mi falta de experiencias en cuanto la resolución de problemas me suelo liar con los enunciados y no consigo traducirlo bien a código. Intentare seguir mejor las normas en cuando a hacer preguntas se refiere hacia un futuro, muchas gracias por las respuestas!

Comment: @JulianOsorio Los agradecientos están muy bien, pero la forma de agradecer en este sitio las cosas es aceptando las respuestas válidas para tu pregunta. Si miras [este enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás cómo se aceptan las respuestas, y si miras este [otro enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) el porqué es importante aceptarlas.  Principalmente para no dejar preguntas sin responder eternamente, pues son relanzadas publicamente de tanto en tanto y distorsionan el uso del sitio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revisa esta solución a ver si te sirve:

```js
function empujarHeroe(arrayHeroes, nuevoHeroe) {
  arrayHeroes.push(nuevoHeroe);
}
superheroes = []
empujarHeroe(superheroes, "Thor")
empujarHeroe(superheroes, "Batman")
empujarHeroe(superheroes, "Mortadelo")
empujarHeroe(superheroes, "Sancho Panza")
console.log(superheroes)
```

Como ves, casi lo tenias, pero habian pequeños errores de sintaxis y de concepto.

**A saber:**

1. En esta función defines *nombres de parámetros* (que son **variables** para usar dentro de la función), no cadenas entrecomilladas `""` ni con sintaxis de `array[]`.
2. Esas **variables** *contienen los valores pasados* cuando llamas a la función con ellas. En este caso en el *primer parámetro* le pasamos como "valor" una variable de array llamada `superheroes` y en el *segundo parámetro* su valor es una *cadena de texto entrecomillada* (aquí si puedes hacerlo).
3. No hace falta que hagas el `return` pues su retorno no lo vamos a asignar a nada. Simplemente agregamos el valor a la variable pasada, que dentro de la función tiene otro nombre, pero es la misma pues esta siendo [pasada por referencia](https://medium.com/laboratoria-developers/por-valor-vs-por-referencia-en-javascript-de3daf53a8b9)
4. Debes definir la variable de array `superheroes` antes de su uso, es decir, `superheroes=[]`. Sino muestra error y no se ejecutará la función con esa variable no definida aún.
5. Para ver el resultado final en **consola** lo debes hacer mediante la función `console.log(variable)` donde `variable` en este caso es `superheroes`

Ejecuta el snippet que he puesto para ver el resultado en consola.

Ya nos diras si te sirve.